# AngularJS and Typescript - Services injected into other services are undefined

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript

I'm using [this starter template](https://github.com/santialbo/AngularJS-TypeScript-Project-Template) with the modifications outlined in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796849/angularjs-typescript-routing).  It has been smooth sailing until now - I'm trying to inject a service into the constructor of another service, but the injected value is always 'undefined'.  There are no errors thrown.

Here is a simplified example:

```
module app.services {
    export class dashboardFilterService implements IService {
        constructor($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
            // $rootScope is undefined...
            //$rootScope.$broadcast('FilterInitialized');
        }
    }
}
app.registerService('dashboardFilterService', ['$rootScope']);
```

Injecting services into controllers works fine.  I am pretty new to typescript as well as angular, so this might be obvious to someone who has more experience with it.  Here is the compiled js for reference:

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    (function (services) {
        var dashboardFilterService = (function () {
            function dashboardFilterService($rootScope) {
                // $rootScope is undefined...
                //$rootScope.$broadcast('FilterInitialized');
            }
            return dashboardFilterService;
        })();
        services.dashboardFilterService = dashboardFilterService;
    })(app.services || (app.services = {}));
    var services = app.services;
})(app || (app = {}));
app.registerService('dashboardFilterService', ['$rootScope']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommended pattern:

```
module app.services {
    export class dashboardFilterService implements IService {
        static $inject = ['$rootScope']; // This should do it
        constructor($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
            //$rootScope.$broadcast('FilterInitialized');
        }
    }
    app.registerService('dashboardFilterService', dashboardFilterService );
}
```

PS: I did a video on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM&hd=1

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know typescript but the safest way to do dependency injection in javascript is

```
app.service('serviceName', ['$rootScope', 'anotherServ', function($rootScope, anotherService){

}]);
```

I think your not passing the service function as the last element in your array, so in your case, something like this:

```
app.registerService('dashboardFilterService', ['$rootScope', dashboardFilterService]);
```

Comment: The app.registerService helper function does actually pass the arguments that way, so I'm still not exactly sure why that method didn't work.  Here is the code:

`export function registerService(className: string, services = []) {
        var service = className[0].toLowerCase() + className.slice(1);
        services.push(() => new app.services[className]());
        angular.module('app.services').factory(service, services);
    }`